# iText: Realign Text position on a PDF page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF page that Logo, 4 address lines and content. I want to realign the 4 address line to the left about 3 - 4 inches, but keep everything else the same. Is it possible to do this using iText java version?

Comment: So you are reading a PDF and want to modify just the address?

Comment: @jzd: yes that is correct. And export the output PDF with the address realign to the left a bit, but the rest stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, thats going to be a hard one. Thats not a typical iText-mission. Good for creating PDFs from scratch, not so good at reading or editing. (You can easily add content though).